# Get class file name in trait

Tags: php, file, class, path, traits

I have `traitA` in `traitA.php` and `classA` in `classA.php` which uses that trait.

I need to get `classA` file name inside of that trait. Can I do it somehow? `__FILE__` returns  `traitA.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLVED**. 
I used

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass('ClassA');
$classFileName = $reflection->getFileName();
```